# Add-Content String Quotes with Variable

Tags: powershell

I am tring to add a line to a text file I created however it needs to contain text quotes around a variable.

An example I am working with:

```
    $wksname="wks12345"
    $path = c:\scripts\file.txt

    Add-Content $path '"DefaultUsername" =' "$wksname"
```

I get an error stating that a positional parameter is not found.

What I would like the output to look like in the text file is:
 "DefaultUsername" = "wks12345"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the escape char **`**

```
$wksname = "TEST123"
write-host "`"DefaultUsername`" = `"$wksname`""
```

Would wrote out **"DefaultUsername" = "TEST123"**

As for the command it should look like

```
$wksname="wks12345"
$path = "c:\scripts\file.txt"
Add-Content -Path $path -Value "`"DefaultUsername`" = `"$wksname`""
```

Answer (score 3):

Use two consecutive `"` as an escape sequence:

```
Add-Content $path """DefaultUsername"" = ""$wksname"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string quoting is wrong.  Here's your command:

```
Add-Content $path '"DefaultUsername" =' "$wksname"
```

You've got three parameters:

```
$path
'"DefaultUsername" =' 
"$wksname"
```

And `Add-Content` only has 2 positional parameters (`-Path` and `-Value`).    PowerShell can't find a third parameter to use.

If you need to use double quotes in a string and you also want to expand variables in your string, you need to escape your double quotes.  There's two ways to do it.

Like this:

```
Add-Content -Path $path -Value """DefaultUsername"" = ""$wksname"""
```

Or this:

```
Add-Content -Path $path -Value "`"DefaultUsername`" = `"$wksname`""
```